# No creator found

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Can you help with this issue,I am facing **No Creator Found** issue when i was retriving data from mongodb using mongodb c# driver.

Here the model class i used

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
class Employee
{

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("country")]
    public string Country{get;set;}
}
```

I was deserializing like

```
var _ListofEmployees = (from emp in _IMongoCollection<Employee>.AsQueryable()

                                select new
                                {
                                    Name = emp.Name,
                                    City = emp.City

                                });

            foreach (var Employee in _ListofEmployee) 
            {
              Console.WriteLine("Name :"+Employee.Name+"\n"+"City :"+Employee.City);
            }
```

**Note:** Country Field is not present in the documents of the mongodb collection

Comment: Which line of code gives you the error ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya inside the foreach while retriving.!!!

Comment: @samathkumar can you paste the full error please

Comment: Seems like you're not using the `BsonIgnoreExtraElements` attribute properly. See [here](http://blog.markstarkman.com/blog/2011/09/22/ignoring-extra-elements-in-mongodb-c-sharp-driver/) for a detailed explanation

Comment: @AmanB i am getting a error of type **No Matching creator found...** .Thanks for the help....`[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` is used when it does not match any of the fields present in document to the fields present in the entity object...But in my case it is perfectly matching and one extra field in present in entity object...However i resolved my issue using `AsEnumerable()` on the collection While retriving...!!!